# Avoiding use of .encode() in rss2html

Tags: python, python-2.x, utf-8, rss

My concern with this code is the excessive use of `.encode('utf-8')`.  Any advice on refining these functions would be very helpful.

[rss2html GitHub repo](https://github.com/Ricky-Wilson/rss2html/blob/master/setup.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

""" Simple rss to html converter """

__version__ = "0.0.1"
__author__ = "Ricky L Wilson"

from feedparser import parse as parsefeed
import StringIO


def entry2html(**kwargs):
    """ Format feedparser entry """
    title = kwargs['title'].encode('utf-8')
    link = kwargs['link'].encode('utf-8')
    description = kwargs['description'].encode('utf-8')
    template = """
    <h2 class='title'>{title}</h2>
    <a class='link' href='{link}'>{title}</a>
    <span class='description'>{description}</span>
    """
    return template.format(title=title, link=link, description=description)


def convert_feed(**kwargs):
    """ Main loop """
    out = StringIO.StringIO("")
    for entry in parsefeed(kwargs['url']).entries:
        title = entry['title']
        link = entry['link']
        description = entry['description']
        print >>out, entry2html(title=title, link=link,
                                description=description)
    return out.getvalue()

print convert_feed(url='http://stackoverflow.com/feeds')
```

Comment: I've removed your new version of the code, since it [adds confusion to the question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357). If you would like further advice, feel free to ask another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work in Unicode and encode at the last moment:

```
def entry2html(**kwargs):
    """ Format feedparser entry """
    template = u"""
    <h2 class='title'>{title}</h2>
    <a class='link' href='{link}'>{title}</a>
    <span class='description'>{description}</span>
    """
    return template.format(**kwargs)

def convert_feed(**kwargs):
    """ Main loop """
    out = u'\n'.join(entry2html(**entry) 
                    for entry in parsefeed(kwargs['url']).entries)
    return out.encode('utf-8')
```

You can pass `entry` directly as `format` does not mind extra keyword arguments. `StringIO` is not necessary for simple concatenation of strings.